# How to view the net contribution of one git branch to another over the entire lifetime of the contributing branch

Tags: git

We have a central MASTER branch and multiple individual task branches, and our lifecycle is something like as follows:

> 1. create individual task branch A from MASTER
> 2. do work on A and complete task
> 3. merge A back into MASTER
> 4. ...if testing identifies additional changes required in A, then merge latest MASTER into A (to bring A back up to speed with tasks
>      B,C,.... that may have been merged into MASTER in the interim)
> 5. fix the issues in branch A
> 6. merge A back into MASTER
> 7. (repeat 4 => 6 until A work signed off)

The above is fine but what we need to do after step 7 is identify (via some kind of GIT diff):

The net changes - after completion of the above lifecycle - that A has introduced into MASTER.

So effectively we are looking for a one-way diff A => MASTER showing the net change introduced by A into MASTER after multiple merges have taken place bidirectionally between the the two branches.

Would greatly appreciate any input I can get on this - thanks!

Comment: Problem is, what you call "branch A" is not really *a part of your history*, just a handle or a shortcut to one commit. What does constitute history is the resulting commit tree. Once branch `A` has been merged into `master`, if you make new commits on `A` then merge again `A` into `master`, this is virtually the same as if you created a new branch `A2` and worked on it instead. Commits brought by the first merge `A > master` don't "remember" that some branch or another was referencing their tip at the time they've been merged into `master`. Parents of a merge are not branches but commits.

Comment: Thanks very much @RomainValeri - is there any way in git to see "all the changes introduced by a particular branch" or is this a pipe dream I'm having?

Comment: Typically, one often uses some variant of `git log master..feature`, where the `master..feature` range means "every commit present on `feature` but NOT on `master`". but the exact nature of the expected result can be different depending on workflows. Some just want a list of all the files which changed. Some want a formatted list of commits, or also a code diff. But the base of the comparison is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your lifecycle model conflicts with the goal of being able to see all changes prior to merging into the baseline, specifically step that merges the topic branch into master *prior to* testing being completed.

Instead, keep all changes in the topic branch until just prior to integration *after* the final signoff. Longer lived topic branches may require a few merges *from* master, that is

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

This way, you perform tests and all other activities in steps 4 through 7 in your topic branch. Immediately prior to final signoff, review cumulative changes with a simple

```
git fetch
git diff origin/master
```

Finally, the exact mechanics of the merge will depend on your workflow.

If you don’t mind potentially messy history in your baseline, simply merge your topic branch.

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only origin/master
git merge topic/fix-potrzebie
```

If your Software Quality organization is good with squash merges

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only origin/master
git merge --squash topic/fix-potrzebie
... fix merge conflicts ...
git commit -m 'PROJ-1234 Fix potrzebie ...'
git push origin master
```

To preserve evidence that the topic branch existed but to collapse it into a single commit. Doing it the hard and risky way looks like

Create a new final version of the topic branch based on the latest baseline.

```
git fetch
git checkout -b topic/fix-potrzebie-final origin/master
```

Collapse the development topic branch to a single commit.

```
git merge --squash topic/fix-potrzebie
... fix merge conflicts ...
git commit -m 'PROJ-1234 Fix potrzebie ...'
```

Merge it back to the baseline.

```
git checkout master
git merge topic/fix-potrzebie-final
git push origin master
```

But there is no reason to do all the merging *again*, which also introduces risk that you may merge different code into the baseline than what was tested. The code already merged and actually tested is addressable as `topic/fix-potrzebie^{tree}`, that is the tree object associated with the commit at the tip of the topic branch. Make a little bumpout with a single commit whose code is the final tree with

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff -m 'Integrate PROJ-1234' \
  $(echo 'PROJ-1234 Fix potrzebie ...' |
      git commit-tree topic/fix-potrzebie^{tree} \
        -p $(git rev-parse origin/master))
```

There is a bit of wizardry in that last command. It creates history of the form

```
$ git lola
*   df6bbc7 (HEAD -> master) Integrate PROJ-1234
|\
| * 0c180a8 PROJ-1234 Fix potrzebie ...
|/
| * 0156bc9 (topic/fix-potrzebie) Updates after testing
| * 0ae9d12 Potrzebie changes
|/
* 61993d0 (origin/master) PROJ-1233 Previous history ...
```

Note that [`git lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) is a non-standard but highly useful alias for

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
```

Note also that no changes exist between the new tip of master and the topic branch

```
$ git diff master topic/fix-potrzebie
[ no output, indicating no differences ]
```

but that they are in fact *identical*, *i.e.*, they have the same SHA-1 hash and thus share the same tree.

```
$ git rev-parse master^{tree} topic/fix-potrzebie^{tree}
9a4fc1bb6230e80bc3a1928a00cb404da6424153
9a4fc1bb6230e80bc3a1928a00cb404da6424153
```

To understand the command, read it in right-to-left order.

1. [`echo $MSG2 | git commit-tree $TREE -p $PARENT`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) is git plumbing that creates a new commit whose tree is `$TREE`, whose parent is `$PARENT`, and whose commit message is `$MSG2`.

   - The tree is the same one already committed at the tip of the topic branch.
   - The parent is `origin/master`, *i.e.*, the current baseline, but converted from a human-readable refname to SHA-1 hash with `git rev-parse`.
   - The output of `git commit-tree` is the SHA-1 hash of the new commit, which becomes `$COMMIT_HASH` in …
2. `git merge --no-ff -m "$MSG1" $COMMIT_HASH` merges the new commit into `master`. Even though we designed it to be a fast-forward, the `--no-ff` switch preserves the brief diverge-then-merge bumpout as an artifact in history.

   - The explanation here flips from single to double quotes to be consistent but I hope not confusing with values coming from environment variables.

At this point, you could delete the now-obsolete topic branch with

```
git branch -D topic/fix-potrzebie
```

to produce tidy history of the form

```
$ git lola
*   df6bbc7 (HEAD -> master) Integrate PROJ-1234
|\
| * 0c180a8 PROJ-1234 Fix potrzebie ...
|/
* 61993d0 (origin/master) PROJ-1233 Previous history ...
```

Finally, share with the rest of the team by

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comprehensive response. I've upvoted it, however I haven't marked it as the accepted answer as our workflow as outlined works extremely well for us as a team. I was/am? hoping for a way of achieving what we need within our existing workflow. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try this instead `gitk` to view difference and others too in UI.